# Kotlin Regex find undesired behavior with startindex

Tags: regex, kotlin

I was trying to find words using regex in Kotlin. Here is a snippet of sample code

```
val possibleString = "#This is a comment"
val regex = "(?<=[ \t\n$PUNC])(\\w+)".toRegex() //PUNC is another char sequence of punctuation 
val matcher1 = regex.find(possibleString)
val matcher2 = regex.find(possibleString,1)
println(matcher1?.value) // this
println(matcher2?.value)  //this
```

The value of matcher 1 makes sense to me, which yields this.
However, why matcher2 also return this? if the start index is 1, don't we start from 'T', and output "is" instead?

I'm wondering why is the case. Do the matcher still scans for the string before index?

If this is the case, I know I could passing substring staring from index 1 to get the desired output. However, consider the possibilities of large chunks of text, generate multiple substring seems waste of memory.
So, is there any efficient workaround?

Thanks!

Comment: sorry, I meant "is". Edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you begin your search at "T", you *will* find `This`, because the `startIndex` is inclusive. A match will be found unless it starts *before* the `startIndex`. If it starts *on* the `startIndex`, it will still be found.

I suspect that your misunderstanding might be thinking that `find` would ignore the the first `#`, because it is before the `startIndex`. **This is not true.** `startIndex` only says where to start - lookbehinds don't suddenly *break* because you started at a later index.

Your desired behaviour isn't how lookbehinds work, so the workaround would be to use a group instead.

```
val regex = "[ \t\n$PUNC](\\w+)".toRegex()
val matcher1 = regex.find(possibleString)
val matcher2 = regex.find(possibleString,1)
println(matcher1?.groups?.get(1)?.value) // This
println(matcher2?.groups?.get(1)?.value) // is
```

You should think of the `startIndex` as the minimum index of the beginning of a match. If you want the match `is` for example, you can start searching from anywhere between index 2 (inclusive) and 6 (inclusive), since `is` starts on index 6:

```
println(regex.find(possibleString, 2).value) // is
```

Comment: Thanks for clarification. This answered my doubts exactly